# Not receiving the information from FIRESTORE , how to wait for the information to arrive? jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am building an app with nested navigation and a screen that fetch profile of celebrities from firestore I have a problem fetching the data before the screen is already loaded and shown. the await() function doesn't make the program wait for the data.

Every time I go to the celeb screen, I want to fetch the fetch the user collection to get the categories of celebs i am intrested in. fetch the userVote collection so that i wont show a Celeb that is already been voted,
then fetch the Celebs collection and filter out the celebs that i dont want to show.

all happen in

retrieveUserVotes()
retrieveCelebs()

i have mad a simple yet complicated example because i need to show the complexity of the code.

also if you think that the way i wrote the code is bad can you explain to me how could i have been write it better?

i am using the navigation explained by phillip lancker youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gUeyNkGE3g&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCSpJ2NLhDTHhi6XBNfk9WiC&index=18&ab_channel=PhilippLackner

github source code
https://github.com/dolev146/stackoverflowexample

i have also made a demo database
[image]
[image]

MainActivity.kt

```
data class Celeb(
    var Company: String,
    var FirstName: String,
    var LastName: String,
    val BirthDate: Long,
    var ImgUrl: String,
    val CelebInfo: String,
    val Category: String,
    var RightVotes: Long = 0,
    var LeftVotes: Long = 0
)

val userVotesCollectionRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("userVotes")
val userCollectionRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
val celebCollectionRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("celebs")
val celebListFilterNames = mutableListOf<String>()
var celebListParam = mutableListOf<Celeb>()


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Navigation()

        }
    }
}



fun retrieveUserVotes()= CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        var userEmail = auth.currentUser?.email.toString()
        userEmail = "v@v.com" // for testing purposes only it is user that already exists in the database
        userVotesCollectionRef.whereEqualTo("userEmail" , userEmail).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                val celebName = document.getString("celebFullName")
                celebListFilterNames.add(celebName.toString())
            }
        }
        println(celebListFilterNames)
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d("Error", "Error: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}




fun retrieveCelebs() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val user = auth.currentUser?.email.toString()
    val userPref = mutableListOf<String>()
    try {
        val docRef = userCollectionRef.document(user)
        val doc = docRef.get().await()
        for (document in doc.data?.entries!!) {
            if (document.key == "userPref") {
                userPref.addAll(document.value as List<String>)
            }
        }
        println(userPref)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("retrieveCelebs", "Error: ${e.message}")
    }


        try {
            val querySnapshot = celebCollectionRef.get().await()
            for (document in querySnapshot.documents) {
                val celebDocument = document
                val celebCompany = celebDocument.data?.get("company").toString()
                val celebFirstName = celebDocument.data?.get("firstName").toString()
                val celebLastName = celebDocument.data?.get("lastName").toString()
                val fullName = "$celebFirstName $celebLastName"
                if(celebListFilterNames.contains(fullName)){
                    continue
                }
                val celebBirthDate = celebDocument.data?.get("birthDate").toString().toLong()
                val celebImgUrl = celebDocument.data?.get("imgUrl").toString()
                val celebInfo = celebDocument.data?.get("celebInfo").toString()
                val celebCategory = celebDocument.data?.get("category").toString()
                if (!userPref.contains(celebCategory)) {
                    continue
                }
                val celebRightVotes = celebDocument.data?.get("rightVotes").toString().toLong()
                val celebLeftVotes = celebDocument.data?.get("leftVotes").toString().toLong()
                val celebObject = Celeb(
                    Company = celebCompany,
                    FirstName = celebFirstName,
                    LastName = celebLastName,
                    BirthDate = celebBirthDate,
                    ImgUrl = celebImgUrl,
                    CelebInfo = celebInfo,
                    Category = celebCategory,
                    RightVotes = celebRightVotes,
                    LeftVotes = celebLeftVotes
                )
                celebListParam.add(celebObject)
            }
            celebListParam.shuffle()


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("error celeb", e.toString())
        }

}
```

Navigation.kt

```
package com.example.stackoverflowexample

import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.SwipeScreen.route) {

        composable(route = Screen.SwipeScreen.route) {
                celebListFilterNames.clear()
                retrieveUserVotes()
                celebListParam.clear()
                retrieveCelebs()
                SwipeScreen()
            }

    }
}
```

SwipeScreen.kt

```
package com.example.stackoverflowexample


import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp


@Composable
fun SwipeScreen() {

    if (celebListParam.isEmpty()) {
        Text(
            text = "bad fire base didnt got the data...",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        )
    } else {
        Text(
            text = "good fire base got the data...",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        )
    }

}
```

Screen (sealed class)

```
package com.example.stackoverflowexample

sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object SwipeScreen : Screen("swipe")
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: should i make a Reproducible Example maybe on github ?

Comment: No, here on StackOverflow.

Comment: should i open a new question or just edit the question here ?

Comment: Edit your actual question.

Comment: ok i am doing a couple of seconds

Comment: i finished editing should i edit it again or is it good ?

Comment: I found the problem!! I was making two coroutine calls concurrently when I wanted them to be one after another

Comment: The code didn't helped me because you do not use navigation in your code . Also the article cost money to be a member premium ofedium and I don't have money untill I will find a job sorry for not being able to pay for your help but I really appreciate it